# tcl v8.5 regex to bind elements to string

Tags: regex, tcl

**The Problem:**
I am trying to convert

```
"%0 %1 ... %n"
```

to

```
"[lindex $someList 0] [lindex $someList 1] ... [lindex $someList n]"
```

with the regex

```
 regsub -all "(%\c*)" $string "\[lindex \$someList \0\]" string
```

and it isn't working - I get, instead:

```
 "[lindex $someList ]0 [lindex $someList ]1 ... [lindex $someList ]n"
```

**The Context:**
Essentially I am trying to write a function that will perform some action over all permutations of a given set of lists (or in other words their cartesian product), for example if I had the following:

```
set action "puts \"%1 hello %0 world\""
```

and a set of lists

```
[1 2 3] [a b]
```

then on invocation of

```
foreach_n $action [list 1 2 3] [list a b]
```

I expect the outcome

```
a hello 1 world
b hello 1 world
a hello 2 world
b hello 2 world
a hello 3 world
b hello 3 world
```

The functions I have written to do this (haven't checked the edge cases fully yet) are:

```
proc foreach_n { action args } {

    foreach el [lindex $args 0] {
        foreach_n_helper $action [list $el] {*}[lrange $args 1 end]
    }
}

proc foreach_n_helper { action fixed_elem_values args } {

    foreach el [lindex $args 0] {
        set fixed_vals [list {*}$fixed_elem_values $el]
        if {[llength $args] > 1} {
            foreach_n_helper $action $fixed_vals {*}[lrange $args 1 end]
        } else {

            #I simply cannot get this bit correct
            regsub -all "(%\c*)" $action "\[lindex \$fixed_vals \0\]" action
            puts "$fixed_vals"
            puts $action
            #eval $action
        }
    }
}
```

and by running

```
foreach_n $action [list 1 2 3] [list a b]
```

I see that the statements I would want to eval for each permutation are:

```
1 a
puts "[lindex $fixed_vals ]1 hello [lindex $fixed_vals ]0 world"
1 b
puts "[lindex $fixed_vals ]1 hello [lindex $fixed_vals ]0 world"
2 a
puts "[lindex $fixed_vals ]1 hello [lindex $fixed_vals ]0 world"
2 b
puts "[lindex $fixed_vals ]1 hello [lindex $fixed_vals ]0 world"
3 a
puts "[lindex $fixed_vals ]1 hello [lindex $fixed_vals ]0 world"
3 b
puts "[lindex $fixed_vals ]1 hello [lindex $fixed_vals ]0 world"
```

So the recursion is as I want it, but the whole thing would crash if I actually tried to eval them since the index is outside of [lindex ...]
As per the document at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regsub.htm I tried bracing the subSpec "[lindex \$fixed_vals \0]" and the output was

```
1 a
puts ""\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"1 hello "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"0 world"
1 b
puts ""\[lindex \$fixed_vals "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"\]"1 hello "\[lindex \$fixed_vals "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"\]"0 world"
2 a
puts ""\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"1 hello "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"0 world"
2 b
puts ""\[lindex \$fixed_vals "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"\]"1 hello "\[lindex \$fixed_vals "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"\]"0 world"
3 a
puts ""\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"1 hello "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"0 world"
3 b
puts ""\[lindex \$fixed_vals "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"\]"1 hello "\[lindex \$fixed_vals "\[lindex \$fixed_vals %\]"\]"0 world"
```

which presumably means I am misinterpreting what was stated in the document (or otherwise ...). I have also tried just "random" twiddling and have gotten nowhere.

Can anyone help? And if there is a better way of accomplishing my goal here I would be happy to hear it.

Note: I realize I could achieve my objective by employing the following pattern:

```
foreach el1 $list1 {
    foreach el2 $list2 {
        .
        .
        .
                  ...    foreach eln $listn {
                             call some function taking n parameters
                         }
                      }
                 ...
     }
 }
```

but this is precisely the pattern I want to avoid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't read every detail. Are you missing the [`subst`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/subst.htm) command?

```
% set string "%0 %1 ... %3" 
%0 %1 ... %3
% set new [regsub -all {%(\d+)} $string {[lindex $someList \1]}]
[lindex $someList 0] [lindex $someList 1] ... [lindex $someList 3]
% set someList {first second third fourth}
first second third fourth
% subst $new
first second ... fourth
```

Comment: This works brilliantly (I only need your third line I think) ... apart from the part where I was matching any alpha-numeric following % instead of at least one digit following % (because only now can I see there is a definition for \d, and I random twiddled out what used to be +) the difference seems (as per the examples on the site I referenced) that I am assigning to the string that is used for the regular expression in place where as you assign to a different variable - unless I am mistaken of course. At any rate thanks for the answer.

Comment: As for the subst command, I had a look at it but it didn't seem to handle regular expressions, and where I might use this there is no reason why I might not reuse elements from some list or swap them around

Comment: What I'm showing is that you use the regular expression to transform your string into code, and then subst to evaluate the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are producing a string in one procedure and then want to substitute tokens in that string with generated strings, a regular expression is possibly the least practical way to do so.

Converting the string `"%0 %1 ... %n"` to `"[lindex $someList 0] [lindex $someList 1] ... [lindex $someList n]"` is fairly straightforward as the resulting string can be constructed from the input string:

```
foreach group "%0 %1 %2 %3" {
    lappend res "\[lindex \$somelist [string range $group 1 end]]"
}
join $res
```

If you want the contents of the input string to select items from a data list it's even simpler:

```
set data [list foo bar baz qux]
set input "%0 %3 %1 %2 %1"
# use lmap in Tcl 8.6
foreach i [lsort -unique $input] d $data {lappend map $i $d}
string map $map $input
# => foo qux bar baz bar
```

And so on. Everything is already in place in Tcl, there's no need to bring in regular expressions.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: I agree that these command sets you mention here would be useful for the sort of strings that I mentioned in my problem example (more for simplicity to show what was going wrong), but for my intended usage (testing C++ code), the amount of data I have to feed to any api which isn't mine to change just to test one case means that any one command, or set of commands won't necessarily be something which prepends only an ordered set of tokens - they could be anything, appearing in any order that makes a valid set of commands.